# How do you tell Rails / the asset pipeline that a js.erb depends on a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, yaml, erb

I have a js.erb file that loads YAML from a config file.  The problem is that Rails / the asset pipeline will cache the results and never invalidate that cache, even when I change the YAML file contents.  I can restart the rails server and even reboot the machine to no avail.  The only workaround I've found so far is doing a "rake assets:clean".

I would like to find a way to tell the asset pipeline that when the YAML file changes, it needs to re-compute my js.erb.  Or, alternatively, tell it it can only cache the js.erb for the lifetime of the rails server / ensure somehow that re-generation occurs every time the rails server comes up or is restarted.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another workaround is to _change the contents_ of the YAML-loading file (add or remove a space somewhere). But your answer looks like a good and complete solution.

Answer (score 4):

Add this into a file under config/initializers and it will tell the asset pipeline to re-compute the js.erb file that loads the YAML data whenever one of the backing YAML files changes:

```
class ConstantsPreprocessor < Sprockets::Processor
  CONSTANTS_ASSET = "support/constants"

  def evaluate(context, locals)
    if (context.logical_path == CONSTANTS_ASSET)
      Constants.load_path.each do |dir|
        dir.each do |yml|
          next unless yml.end_with?".yml"
          context.depend_on("#{dir.path}/#{yml}")
        end
      end
    end

    data
  end
end

Rails.application.assets.register_preprocessor(
    'application/javascript',
    ConstantsPreprocessor)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Sprockets 3](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/3.x/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb#L258) (with Rails 5, for example), you can use `// depends_on`. For example, `my-constants.js.erb`:

```
//= depend_on my_constants.yml
angular
  .module('services.myConstants', [])
  .factory('myConstants', [
    function() {
      return <%= YAML::load_file(Rails.root.join('config/shared/my_constants.yml')).to_json %>;
    }
  ]);
```

Just make sure the directory containing `my_constants.yml` is included in asset paths in `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths.unshift Rails.root.join('config', 'shared').to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options:

1. Disable the asset pipeline and let Rails do the compilation on the go (bad for performance)
2. Create a daemon process, separated from Rails (look for Ruby Daemon) to look for any changes in that specific file and recompile the assets.

3 (extra!). Remove the js-YAML dependency and read the content of the YAML from a AJAX call to the app. The scenario is: the JS make a AJAX call, the controller read the YAML file and return the content of it to the JS file. So no need to recompile or watch for changes in the YAML file.

- if you choose the 3, don't read the YAML in the controller, create a utility class to do it and let the controller ask that class to read the file and pass it's content.

Comment: For option 1, the problem is it's bad for performance, as you mentioned.  For option 2, recompiling all assets will take way too long, or if you're suggesting a way to only recompile the single changed asset, I don't understand your proposal of how to do it.  Option 3 seems promising and I'll give it a try, but it seems like there's got to be a cleaner way to do this.  Also, can you provide a more concrete example of what you have in mind for option 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own processor directive that works on files outside of the `assets` directory.  `= depend_on` only works with asset files (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#depend_on)

In config/initializers/sprockets.rb:

```
Sprockets::DirectiveProcessor.class_eval do
  def process_depend_on_project_file_directive(file)
    path = Rails.root.join(file).to_s
    if File.exists?(path)
      deps = Set.new
      deps << @environment.build_file_digest_uri(path)
      @dependencies.merge(deps)
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

`//= depend_on_project_file "config/setting.yml"`

See this comment on github for details: https://github.com/rails/sprockets/issues/500#issuecomment-491043517